# Apply hook to certain routes Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, hook

I am building an app using Node.js. I wrote an authentication middleware that I want to be applied to ALL routes, except my /index and /login routes. Is there a way I can prevent the hook from applying to my /index and /login routes? My current code:

My `app.js`:

```
var middleware = require('./methods/authentication.js');
app.use(middleware.authenticate) //this makes it apply to ALL routes
```

My  `authentication.js`:

```
module.exports = {
authenticate: function(req, res, next) {
    var cookie = parseCookie.parseCookie(req.headers.cookie);
    user.returnUser(cookie, function(result) {
        if(result.length > 1) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a shim that looks at the route and only calls the authenticate function if the path is not one of your exceptions:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.path === "/index" || req.path === "/login") {
      next();
  } else {
      middleware.authenticate(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

Here's a version that uses a `Map` object that is more easily extensible to a longer list of paths:

```
var ignorePaths = new Map(["/index", "/login"]);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (ignorePaths.has(req.path)) {
      next();
  } else {
      middleware.authenticate(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

Comment: Just curios what would be the cost of this "if" condition considering every request (10's of 1000's of them) will be evaluated?

Comment: @user3658423 - If you want to execute something on every route but these two routes, something has to check if it's one of those two routes.  You can't escape that.  And, if you could tell the difference in a request processing elapsed time with one less `if` statement, I'd be very surprised.  There's LOTS of other things already going on in processing  a request.

Comment: @user3658423 - If you have more than just two paths to check, you could preload the paths into a map object and do a more efficient map lookup, but I'm not sure if that's more efficient for just two paths.

Comment: @user3658423 - I added the `Map` example to my answer.

Comment: thnanks @jfriend00!!